# std::variant<> template wrapper class for different std::variant<> types

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to write a template class for `std::variant<>` that could hold and manage different `std::variant<>` containers, for example one template should manage `std:variant<int, double>` and the other `std::variant<int, double, std::string, std::vector<int>>`.
The main problem might be class member **`iVariant`** defined as a **`typename`**.

My code looks like this so far.

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<uint8_t> byte_array_t;

typedef std::variant <std::monostate, int, unsigned int, int64_t, uint64_t, std::string, bool, double, byte_array_t>  variant_long;
typedef std::variant <std::monostate, int, unsigned int, int64_t, uint64_t, double>  variant_short; 

template <typename VariantType = variant_long>
class VariantHolder
{
    private:
        VariantType iVariant;

    public:
        VariantHolder()
        {
        }
        ~VariantHolder()
        {
        }
        template< typename T>
        void EmplaceValue( T aValue )
        {
            iVariant.emplace<T>( aValue );
        }

        /* Invoke HoldsValue()<T> first to make sure that VariantHolder is capable of returning T-type value */
        template< typename T>
        T GetValue()
        {
            return std::get<T>( iVariant );
        }

        template< typename T>
        bool HoldsValue()
        {
            return std::holds_alternative<T>( iVariant ) ? true : false;
        }

        bool IsEmpty()
        {
            return std::holds_alternative<std::monostate>( iVariant ) ? true : false ;
        }
        void Clear()
        {
            EmplaceValue( std::monostate{} );
        }
};



int main()

{
    VariantHolder<variant_long> lVariant;


lVariant.EmplaceValue<int>(64);

if( lVariant.HoldsValue<int>() )
{
    auto lIntVal = lVariant.GetValue<int>();
    std::cout << lIntVal;
}

// VariantHolder<variant_long> lVariant;
// lVariant.EmplaceValue("std-string");

// if( lVariant.HoldsValue<std::string>() )
// {
//     auto lIntVal = lVariant.GetValue<std::string>();
//     std::cout << lIntVal;
// }

return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error in function

```
template< typename T>
            void EmplaceValue( T aValue )
            {
                iVariant.emplace<T>( aValue );
            }
```

Which says

expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token iVariant.emplace( aValue );

Is is actually possible to achieve such a template class in this case?

Comment: `iVariant.emplace<T>` -> `iVariant.template emplace<T>`.

Comment: `iVariant.template emplace<T>( aValue );`